# How to include custom jar in elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I m new to elastic search. I was using SOLR initially.
Like in SOLR we can include an external jar in solrconfig.xml in lib dir and then use it in schema in field type defination.
How can i do the same in elastic Search.